# OpenCV - Speeding up the computation of SSD of 3x3 patches

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

As part of a bigger application, I need to compute the following code:

```
ax2 += (int)(25 + 0.5);
ay2 += (int)(25 + 0.5);

bx2 += (int)(25 + 0.5);
by2 += (int)(25 + 0.5);

cx2 += (int)(25 + 0.5);
cy2 += (int)(25 + 0.5);

    for (int ix = -1; ix <= 1; ix++){
        for (int iy = -1; iy <= 1; iy++){
            suma += (grayImage.at<uchar>(ay2 + iy, ax2 + ix) - grayImage.at<uchar>(by2 + iy, bx2 + ix))* grayImage.at<uchar>(ay2 + iy, ax2 + ix) - grayImage.at<uchar>(by2 + iy, bx2 + ix));
}
}
```

It basically computes the sum of squared difference of two 3X3 patches.

It runs extremely slow. Is there any way of speeding it up?

EDIT:

I changed to the following version:

```
for (int ix = -1; ix <= 1; ix++){
        for (int iy = -1; iy <= 1; iy++){
            double difa = grayImage.at<uchar>(ay2 + iy, ax2 + ix) - grayImage.at<uchar>(by2 + iy, bx2 + ix);
            suma += (difa)*(difa);
        }
}
```

And it runs faster, but is there any way to improve it further?

Thanks,

Gil.

EDIT: following the comment and the answer, I'm not using the following code:

```
//int iy = -1;
     Mi_a = grayImage.ptr<uchar>(ay2 - 1);
     Mi_b = grayImage.ptr<uchar>(by2 - 1);
     Mi_c = grayImage.ptr<uchar>(cy2 - 1);

    difa = Mi_a[ax2 - 1] - Mi_b[bx2 - 1];
    suma += (difa)*(difa);
    difc = Mi_c[cx2 - 1] - Mi_b[bx2 - 1];
    sumc += (difc)*(difc);
    difa = Mi_a[ax2 + 0] - Mi_b[bx2 + 0];
    suma += (difa)*(difa);
    difc = Mi_c[cx2 + 0] - Mi_b[bx2 + 0];
    sumc += (difc)*(difc);
    difa = Mi_a[ax2 + 1] - Mi_b[bx2 + 1];
    suma += (difa)*(difa);
    difc = Mi_c[cx2 + 1] - Mi_b[bx2 + 1];
    sumc += (difc)*(difc);



    //int iy=0;
    Mi_a = grayImage.ptr<uchar>(ay2 + 0);
    Mi_b = grayImage.ptr<uchar>(by2 + 0);
    Mi_c = grayImage.ptr<uchar>(cy2 + 0);

    difa = Mi_a[ax2 - 1] - Mi_b[bx2 - 1];
    suma += (difa)*(difa);
    difc = Mi_c[cx2 - 1] - Mi_b[bx2 - 1];
    sumc += (difc)*(difc);
    difa = Mi_a[ax2 + 0] - Mi_b[bx2 + 0];
    suma += (difa)*(difa);
    difc = Mi_c[cx2 + 0] - Mi_b[bx2 + 0];
    sumc += (difc)*(difc);
    difa = Mi_a[ax2 + 1] - Mi_b[bx2 + 1];
    suma += (difa)*(difa);
    difc = Mi_c[cx2 + 1] - Mi_b[bx2 + 1];
    sumc += (difc)*(difc);


    //int iy=1
    Mi_a = grayImage.ptr<uchar>(ay2 + 1);
    Mi_b = grayImage.ptr<uchar>(by2 + 1);
    Mi_c = grayImage.ptr<uchar>(cy2 + 1);

    difa = Mi_a[ax2 - 1] - Mi_b[bx2 - 1];
    suma += (difa)*(difa);
    difc = Mi_c[cx2 - 1] - Mi_b[bx2 - 1];
    sumc += (difc)*(difc);
    difa = Mi_a[ax2 + 0] - Mi_b[bx2 + 0];
    suma += (difa)*(difa);
    difc = Mi_c[cx2 + 0] - Mi_b[bx2 + 0];
    sumc += (difc)*(difc);
    difa = Mi_a[ax2 + 1] - Mi_b[bx2 + 1];
    suma += (difa)*(difa);
    difc = Mi_c[cx2 + 1] - Mi_b[bx2 + 1];
    sumc += (difc)*(difc);
```

Or it's looped version which has the same running time:

```
for (int iy = -1; iy <= 1; iy++)
    {
        const uchar * Mi_a = grayImage.ptr<uchar>(ay2 + iy);
        const uchar * Mi_b = grayImage.ptr<uchar>(by2 + iy);
        const uchar * Mi_c = grayImage.ptr<uchar>(cy2 + iy);
        for (int ix = -1; ix <= 1; ix++)
        {
            double difa = Mi_a[ax2 + ix] - Mi_b[bx2 + ix];
            suma += (difa)*(difa);

            double difc = Mi_c[cx2 + ix] - Mi_b[bx2 + ix];
            sumc += (difc)*(difc);
        }
    }
```

Is there any way to speed it even further?

Thanks

Gil

Comment: Without knowing what grayImage is, extract `ax2 + ix` and `bx2 + ix` from inner loop. What is `grayImage` deffinition?

Comment: Thanks @TioPepe, grayImage is an openCV Mat. Do you mean I should compute the sum of ax2+ix outside of the loop? Thanks

Comment: `ax2+ix` and `bx2+ix` can be computed in the outer loop once for each y loop.

Comment: Thanks @Micka. What about the "at" operator? will direct access (though grayImage.data) will be faster? and how exactly can I implement it? Thanks

Comment: you can try to use openCV functions: `cv::Rect subA2(ax2-1, ay2-1, 3,3);` and `cv::Rect subB2(bx2-1, by2-1, 3,3);` then `cv::Mat result = grayImage(subA2) - grayImage(subB2); result = result.mul(result);` and then some openCV reduce function. Maybe that'll use SSE instructions or sth, but no guarantee that it will be faster ;)

Comment: @GilLevi direct acces might be faster, but using release mode with optimization is minor improvement compared to direct access. But here's how you can do it: http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/core/how_to_scan_images/how_to_scan_images.html

Comment: as Tio Pepe suggests in his answer, the biggest speed improvement will be to iterate the y coordinate in the outer loop and the x coordinate in the inner loop. that's because of the memory layout used by matrices/images. Probably that will be already sufficient for your needs, the rest is quite minor speed improvement only.

Comment: I`d recommend to also unroll inner (or and even outer) loop - it might speed up sometimes a lot.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the helpful tips!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [OpenCv Mat documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat)

> If you need to process a whole row of a 2D array, the most efficient way is to get the pointer to the row first, and then just use the plain C operator []

So:

```
for (int iy = -1; iy <= 1; iy++)
{
    const uchar * Mi_a = grayImage.ptr<uchar>(ay2 + iy);
    const uchar * Mi_b = grayImage.ptr<uchar>(by2 + iy);

    for (int ix = -1; ix <= 1; ix++)
    {
        double difa = Mi_a[ax2 + ix] - Mi_b[bx2 + ix]
        suma += (difa)*(difa);
    }    
}
```

Comment: oh yes, thats something I forgot, always compute row by row, so that the outer loop is the row indexing and inner loop the column. That way, there's much better caching possible because of the memory layout of matrices/images.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Tio Pepe, I've edited my question according to your answer. Is there any way to speed it even further? Thanks in advance.