# manual grayscale in opencv is too slow

Tags: c++, opencv, optimization, grayscale

Note: I have to do this manually so don't suggest me to use the library function cvtColor().

I'm new to opencv and I am trying to grayscale an color image with the formula

(r,g,b) = (r,g,b)/((r+g+b)/3)

Here is my method(C++) for converting to grayscale:

```
    Mat dst = src.clone();
for (int i= 0; i<src.rows; ++i)
{
    for (int j = 0 ; j < src.cols; ++j)
    {
        Vec3b myVec = dst.at<Vec3b>(i,j);

        uchar temp = (myVec[0]+myVec[1]+myVec[2])/3;
        Vec3b newPoint(temp,temp,temp);
        dst.at<Vec3b>(i,j) = newPoint ;
    }
}
```

Because I want to grayscale a video so I use this method to grayscale each of its frame.
It is really slow in comparison with using the cvtColor(src,dst,CV_RGB2GRAY). (I only waitkey(1) so it is not the problem of waitkey)

I have 2 questions

1. I just wonder if there are any way to manually grayscale an image that is as fast as cvtColor. If not do you guy know how to optimize the above code so that the grayscale video appears to be smoother.
2. The above is just one approach to grayscale.
   (r,g,b) = (r,g,b)/((r+g+b)/3)
   Can you guy tell me about all other approaches for grayscale a color image?

Any answer would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know OpenCV, buy you don't need to call `::at` every time there.  Why not call it once, save the data, and assign once?

Comment: You right it is clearly better a little bit when I replace the block of code inside the for loop with this

    Vec3b myVec = dst.at<Vec3b>(i,j);

   uchar temp = (myVec[0]+myVec[1]+myVec[2])/3;
   Vec3b newPoint(temp,temp,temp);
   dst.at<Vec3b>(i,j) = newPoint ;

Comment: but it is still not as smooth as video flow. Any idea?

Comment: My question is why not use the inbuilt `opencv` greyscale conversion? They probably do some funky aligned memory stuff to make it faster.

Comment: `Mat::at` returns a reference - you don't need to copy it out and back. Though it's *possible* the optimiser may remove the inefficiency, it'd be reassuring to code ala `Vec3b& v = dst.at<Vec3v>(i,j); v[0] = v[1] = v[2] = (v[0] + v[1] + v[2]) / 3;`.  Separately, `Mat` offers `begin` and `end` functions to get iterators - that may be more efficient than finding each pixel from `(i,j)` coordinates - which implies a considerable amount of multiplication or bit shifting and addition.  Look at `Mat::begin` [here](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html) for an example.

Comment: @Ben: That is the request from my professor. He said because we are new to it, we need to do almost everything manually.

Comment: You usually want to weight the colors, typically something like `grey = 0.3 * R + 0.6 * G + 0.1 * B;`. The obvious way to do it faster is to do more in parallel--running the code on the graphics card (e.g., using Cuda or OpenCL) would probably be the most obvious (this is exactly the sort of problem for which graphics cards are optimized).

Comment: grayscale is not (r+g+b)/3, check the [formula](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html?highlight=cvtcolor#cv.CvtColor). Also, what's wrong with convert(BGR2GRAY)? It works faster, use a better formula, and your video is gray after that. If you read your video in YUV format, you can also consider Y as a grayscale image

Comment: If you want it to be fast - don't use the "at" operator. I recently asked how to speed up my code, take a look, it might give you hints on how to speed up yours: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24286624/opencv-speeding-up-the-computation-of-ssd-of-3x3-patches

Comment: Is it a requirement that `dst` have three channels? Your computation will be faster if you only output a single-channeled image. This computation is probably memory-bound, so the less memory access you do, the faster it will be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can tell you that the ::at function is slow.

I always use a struct and a pointer here is an rgb example:

```
#pragma pack(push, 2)
 struct RGB {        //members are in "bgr" order!
   uchar blue;
   uchar green;
   uchar red;  
 };
```

And then acces the pixels of you image like this:

```
RGB& rgb = image.ptr<RGB>(y)[x]; //y = row, x = col
```

Change pixel values (for an RGB image) like this:

```
image.ptr<RGB>(y)[x].value[0] = 142;
image.ptr<RGB>(y)[x].value[1] = 255;
image.ptr<RGB>(y)[x].value[2] = 90;
```

You can translate that into your grayscale problem pretty easy. The good thing about this is, that its really fast because a scanline of an cv::Mat image are not split in the memory the pixels of one scanline are next to each other in the memory.