# Sobel Android C++ OpenCV Without Library

Tags: android, c++, image, opencv, sobel

I'm trying to implement sobel edge detection using C++ in android studio with minimum library help. I have to write the algorithm by myself so I cannot use sobel or any function provided by OpenCV.

The problem is the output given looks abstract like this 
[output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X65nY.jpg). I cannot find any relevant discussion for this.

I'm using a 4 channel 8UC4 mat, with JNI calls to the c++. and struct to contain the image, described here [stackoverflow.com/questions/24319406/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319406/manual-grayscale-in-opencv-is-too-slow)

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks a lot.

here is the code snippet :

```
#pragma pack(push, 2)
struct RGB {      
  uchar red;
  uchar green;
  uchar blue;
  float alfa;
};
```

the above code shows the struct

```
extern "C"
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
Java_com_example_rakad_skripsi_1c_1realtime_RealTimeDetection_gscale(JNIEnv *env, jobject, jlong frame){
Mat& Frame = *(Mat*)frame;

int row = Frame.rows;
int col = Frame.cols;

GaussianBlur( Frame, Frame, Size( 7, 7), 0, 0 ); // Optional Noise Reduction

for (int y = 0; y < row; y++) {
    for (int x = 0; x < col; x++) {
        //GET PIXEL VALUE
        RGB& frm = Frame.ptr<RGB>(y)[x];
        uchar gray = (frm.blue * 0.587) + (frm.green * 0.114) + (frm.red * 0.299); //Grayscale

        //REPLACE PIXEL VALUE
        frm.red = gray;
        frm.blue = gray;
        frm.green = gray;
    }
  }
}
```

the above code is the grayscale method. this method works fine without any trouble with 20+ fps real time.

```
extern "C"
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
Java_com_example_rakad_skripsi_1c_1realtime_RealTimeDetection_sobel(JNIEnv *env, jobject, jlong frame){
Mat& Frame = *(Mat*)frame;

int row = Frame.rows;
int col = Frame.cols;

/*SOBEL OPERATOR MATRIX

    Gx =    [   -1   0   1  ]       Gy =    [    1    2    1   ]
            [   -2   0   2  ]               [    0    0    0   ]
            [   -1   0   1  ]               [   -1   -2   -1   ]
 */

/*IMAGE MATRIX

  Image =   [   1   2   3   ]
            [   4   5   6   ]
            [   7   8   9   ]
 */

for (int x = 0; x < row; x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < col; y++) {

        int gradX, gradY, grad = 0;
        RGB& mid = Frame.ptr<RGB>(x)[y];

        if (x == 0 || x == row-1 || y == 0 || y == col-1){

            gradX = gradY = 0;

        } else {

            RGB& px1 = Frame.ptr<RGB>(x-1)[y-1];   RGB& px2 = Frame.ptr<RGB>(x)[y-1];     RGB& px3 = Frame.ptr<RGB>(x+1)[y-1];
            RGB& px4 = Frame.ptr<RGB>(x-1)[y];                                            RGB& px6 = Frame.ptr<RGB>(x+1)[y];
            RGB& px7 = Frame.ptr<RGB>(x-1)[y+1];   RGB& px8 = Frame.ptr<RGB>(x)[y+1];     RGB& px9 = Frame.ptr<RGB>(x+1)[y+1];

            gradX = (px1.red * (-1)) + (px4.red * (-2)) + (px7.red * (-1)) + (px3.red) + (px6.red * 2) + (px9.red);

            gradY = (px7.red * (-1)) + (px8.red * (-2)) + (px9.red * (-1)) + (px1.red) + (px2.red * 2) + (px3.red);

        }

        grad = sqrt((gradX*gradX) + (gradY*gradY));
        saturate_cast<uchar>(grad);

        mid.red = grad;
        mid.green = grad;
        mid.blue = grad;
    }
  }
}
```

the above code is the trouble. it shows the picture mentioned before.

Comment: the coefficients for the greyscale calculation are not correctly applied: (0.299,0.587,0.114)*(R,G,B)

Comment: @rpress thanks a lot, I've edited the code. But i think it's not relevant to my actual problem because I'm still having it. Any other suggestion?

Comment: Your code doesn't normalize the gradient values. Divide them by the sums of the absolute values of the operator matrices.

Comment: Hi, I tried your solution but I get all black images. how to normalize properly?

Comment: If the code in your question is still the code you use: there's another major problem in it. You should not write the output into the same buffer. Write into a separate output buffer and copy the result back at the end.

Comment: Do you mean use another Mat to store the result and copy the result back to main Mat& Frame?

Comment: Yes, because you apply 3x3 filters. You cannot easily do this in-place because pixel values get overwritten and the calculations for the neighboring pixels use the new values, not the original ones.